# Firebase: How to get User.uid?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uid

I'm using Firebaseauth to manage users and data for my iOS app. The users can log in, and their userinfo is stored correct in the database. 
But when I try to get the users to write to the database in a different viewController, using this string:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

The thrown error is

> Type user has no member .uid

That makes sense I guess, since I haven't created the variable. But I can't figure out how to declare it?

Comment: You're supposed to pass the info to the next view controller. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151) will be helpful

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is how you get the user's uid:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

**UPDATE:** Since this answer is getting upvotes, make sure you prevent your app from crashing by using `guard`s:

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

Comment: A force unwrap may crash your app. Check Victor's answer to see how to prevent this.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use a guard, as a force unwrap might break your app if a user isn’t signed in.

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRAuth has actually been renamed to Auth. So, as per the latest changes, it will be

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

Edit.

As pointed out in comments, A force unwrap may crash the app.

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

Comment: A force unwrap may crash your app. Check Victor's answer to see how to prevent this.